# Extending string matching algorithms to search for a pattern of real numbers

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

How to extend naive string matching algorithm to search for a pattern of real numbers when both Pattern and Text are saved in floating point arrays? What are the assumptions we have to make?

Comment: You can't save text in a floating point array.

Comment: Here Text means the original pattern we are searching for matching with our smaller pattern.Pattern and Text both are floating point numbers.

Comment: This is a misconception a string (text) is not a floating point number even if it contains only digits.

Comment: there are no strings in the scenario.There are only patterns of floating point numbers.you have misunderstood.Pattern and Text are 2 names I have used to refer them as that's the general way used in string matching algorithms.

Comment: If there are no strings in the scenario, what does it have to do with string matching algorithms (which ONLY deal with strings)? Your question is very unclear. You are either dealing with floating point numbers, in which case there is no matching needed (they ARE floating point numbers), or you are dealing with strings that may contain string representations of floating point numbers. In the latter case, the assumptions you have to make are: what are the valid formats of string representations of floating point numbers.

Comment: You shouldn't have to extend the string matching algorithm, you can just convert the float to a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just take floating point number array as a string** and then apply the string matching matching algorithm

example: Text[1.2,3.45,5.123] and Pattern[1.2,3.45]

Then string will look like,
Text[]="1.23.455.123" and Pattern[]="1.23.45"
Now we can match pattern with text using naive.